fill the child window inside a parent paned window tkinter python
Drag and drop the child window inside a parent paned window using tkinter python. when dropped child window need to fill the size of the pane.
I am using this code to create a paned window
panel_divider = tk.PanedWindow(orient="horizontal", background = "Black")
panel_divider.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

tool_panel = ctk.CTkFrame(panel_divider)

child window code
class Properties(ctk.CTkToplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("Properties")
        self.geometry("250x600")

i am just trying to dock and undock a child window inside a main window pane and fill it to the size of the pane.

There's not enough code here for us to reproduce the problem. Please make sure that your example is minimal, but also complete. See [mcve].

Toplevel is a separate window. It can be above the parent window or behind the parent window. This is not that child that can be dragged and dropped inside the parent window. Describe in more detail what your program does and provide more code.
